# How to plot Telescopic Chart in D3 or Python

Tags: python, d3.js, plot

I have a time series with seconds level monthly data for 3 months.

**['timestamp', 'data_series']**
**[2015-01-01 00:00:01, 1.02], [2015-01-01 00:00:02, 1.04], [2015-01-01 00:00:03, 1.01]........ [2015-01-02 00:00:01, 1.08], [2015-01-02 00:00:02, 1.05]...**

Suppose I want to plot a telescopic like "**line chart**" (e.g. first monthly line, then weekly, then daily, then hourly, then second level), how can it be done using D3 and Python or Python alone?

Could someone provide full working code?

[image: Something like this Chart should like]

Comment: did you try something on your own ?

Comment: This is not a question. You're effectively asking someone else to do your work and provide you with full working code. People would be more inclined if you put in some effort, hit some stumbling block then came here with a question showing what you tried and identifying a specific problem.

Comment: Only you can provide full working code.

Comment: I am new to Python and D3 and do not have enough competency to code that way so why I asked. I searched a lot on internet but no tutorials available. I thought this site could help.